# Can Array.prototype.includes() search for an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the following code:

```js
let a = [
  ["10.237.77.82", "10.237.79.255"],
  ["10.237.78.2", "230.0.0.1"],
  ["10.237.78.2", "10.237.79.255"]
]
console.log(a.includes(["10.237.77.82", "10.237.79.255"]))
```

I was expecting the `includes()` to find the Array `["10.237.77.82", "10.237.79.255"]`, why isn't it the case?

[Array.prototype.includes() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) does not seem to suggest specific elements which are "foundable" (although the examples are only with an Integer or a String)

Comment: `console.log([] === [])` --> false

Comment: Looks like it works only with primitives

Comment: It does only work with primitives. There not a single example that uses arrays.

Comment: You can just convert each element to string.

console.log(a.join("").includes("10.237.77.82", "10.237.79.255"));

Comment: `includes` will work work on objects/array, if two objects refer to the same Object.

Comment: Here's my workaround: [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/j9xvhnum/36/)